# jQuery create a empty DIV, load extern html Resource and remove the same with click

Tags: jquery

i try to load a html File in a div and to remove the html with a click on a id inside the html Resource.
Clicking on id="load" create a empty div (id="externContent") within div (id="showContent") and load the extern Resource extern.php #wrapp into id="externContent". Successfully
Click on id="close" deletes extern Resource inside div id="externContent". Successfully

Why does not it click on id="closeExtern" deletes extern Resource inside div id="externContent".

### Basic html

```
<div id="load">Load</div>
<div id="close">Close/div>id
<div id="showContent"></div>
```

### Script in Basic html

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    $('#showContent').append('<div id="externContent"></div>');
    $('#externContent').empty();
    $('#externContent').load('extern.php #wrapp');
});
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#externContent').empty();
});
$('#closeExtern').click(function() {
    $('#externContent').empty();
});
```

### load extern.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapp">
some content
<span id="closeExtern">CloseExtern/span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `.empty()` before `.load()`. Especially since you just created the empty DIV.

Comment: You need to use `$("#showContent").on("click", "#closeExtern", function()...);` to bind to the dynamically-loaded DIV.

Comment: $("#showContent").on("click", ".#closeExtern", function(){
 $("#externContent").empty();   
});